# CSS move multiple list item to the right and up

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items on my page that are in a vertical column (shape wise not HTML5 column) and I want one or many of the items to move to the right and essentially drop out of the set and move all the way back to the top inline.

Something like

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
<ul>
```

would go to

```
<ul>      <li>
  <li>
  <li>
<ul>
```

I know this can be done with an absolute position but it is supposed to be done in dynamic fashion, such that the items will be rendered and then moved, so I was wondering if there is any trick out there in CSS land that can make this possible. Sorry for the limited knowledge of the extent of the situation.  A pure javascript (not jquery or other lib) solution that would work in IE7 could potentially work, maybe just a solution that does a count on object that have an absolute positioning and then uses the count and height to determine the top value?

Thanks for listening, looking, and maybe helping!

P.S. http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/LpXn5/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/LpXn5/4/ depending on if you like divs or lists (i don't care if you can make it work one way or the other)

Comment: It's not a complete solution, but you could use the `*-column-count` CSS property and then make it so only one `<li>` element appears in the second column.

Comment: Your best approach is absolute positioning. Could you elaborate on the dynamic fashion part?

Comment: added further explanation to "dynamic fashion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indicated a fixed width for the list items, so this can be easily generated using:

```
#list li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0
}
```

Since you have a fixed width, I don't understand what you mean by dynamic? Anyway, here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LpXn5/23/).

Comment: Rebuttal as in you changed the question? :P

Comment: "Rebuttal" being a counter-argument.  The problem is that that method only works as the first-child and no subsequent children

Comment: I do understand English. Did you actually check the updated code and jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/LpXn5/23/

Comment: I did. However add a second item to the right hand side and top: 0; will encompass BOTH items and we will visibly lose one of the items, not DOM wise but still is not a feasible option.

Comment: Stop moving the goalposts, then. Your original question asked for one element (as did your example).

Comment: @BenM His title always said multiple list items never last one. You know how to do it for multiple li without knowing the size of the li? Just hit the end of a div and then move to the right?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BenM's answer but if you want to move it to the right, maybe you should try this instead:

```
#list li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pf9eQ/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`float:right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) for the first list item, and `float` the other list items to the left.

```
#list {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    float: left;
}

#list li:first-child {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LpXn5/15/)

Comment: @BenM By dynamic does he mean always on the top right corner?

Comment: I think so, see his 'rebuttal' to my answer.

Comment: I want the items (at any position in the list) to move up and fall inline (block), similar to the left hand side but on the right